# Who are Coulson's parents in Agents of SHIELD?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

Do we ever find out who Coulson's parents are?

Comment: Dr and Mr Coulson, of course.

Comment: What relevance would it have?

Comment: The MCU wiki gives their names as [Robert](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Robert_Coulson) and [Julie](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Julie_Coulson) but I'm not sure where they're getting them from.

Comment: @OrangeDog Lots of questions don't have any relevance; what does it matter?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot because we don't want a site full of tedious trivia?

Comment: @OrangeDog Don't we? We certainly don't mind it here and in a lot of cases it is very positively received. Maybe you're thinking of M&TV where they have the trivia close reason. Also in this case when you go digging into it, the answer is (maybe) there and it's quite interesting from a research perspective.

Comment: I'll just go ask "Who are Caoulson's grandparents in AoS", "What colour ties does Fury own", and "In S4E12 what brand is the phone on the desk" then?

Comment: @OrangeDog It appears you forgot to @ me. And sure you _can_, but Coulson's parents are actually mentioned a few times in the series so it is somewhat reasonable to ask, grandparents, go ahead but meh. The ties question would get downvoted because either we see the ties (then it's super easy so meh) or we don't. The brand of phone could be quite a good question, we've had ones along similar lines before that have been quite popular.

Comment: Mr. and Mrs. Coul (after all, he is the “son” of Coul) 

Answer (score 4):

There's a S.H.I.E.L.D. file out there on Coulson which lists his father and mother's names as Robert and Julie.

[image: Two SHIELD Files on Coulson, Family section quoted below]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

> Family:
>
> Robert Coulson, Father DECEASED 09-22-1987
> Julie Coulson, Mother DECEASED 09-22-1992

However, this source is a bit dubious. It appears to have been present on the [S.H.I.E.L.D. Files](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/S.H.I.E.L.D._Files) page of the MCU Wiki at one point in time but has since been removed. I found this one over on the Marvel Cinematic Database's page [S.H.I.E.L.D. Files](https://marvelcinematicdatabase.fandom.com/wiki/S.H.I.E.L.D._Files) but this wiki is less trustworthy than the MCU Wiki. On top of that the dates for the parents being the same apart from the years is a tad odd.

This is the only source I've found so far for their names but I'm not entirely sure where it has come from so I wouldn't trust it completely as I know there were fan creations of these files going around at one point. I could be wrong and it might be legitimate so I'd be interested in finding out where it came from.

Comment: The file _may_ come from _The Avengers_ DVD extras but I can't check that myself to be sure.